# How can I get only textures (with out shaders) from rendering image in Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, rendering, texturing, shaders

I want to get Only texture with out shaders from rendering image.

In my rendering image.

[image]

I want to output a texture-only image like displayed inside the red frame of this image.

I want an image that looks like *Solid* in *Viewport Shading* and the colors are from textures.

[image]

Screenshots are not an option, because I want to match the size with the rendered image.

I can write Python, so I'm more glad if I can get it with a script.

Comment: Just use the texture color directly to the surface output, with no shader in between.

Comment: @lemon Thanks for reply. but I don't know how do I do what *texture color directly to the surface output.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-You can enable color pass in view layer settings. And access it in compositing.

2-You can do screenshot of the solid with right size by doing Viewport render image.
Its in view menu of viewport.

3-About

> Just use the texture color directly to the surface output, with no
>   shader in between. – lemon

With Node wrangler addon shift-click on texture in material editor to show just texture.
Or connect texture to emission shader and this shader to output node.